# Spacing error with multicols

Tags: spacing, multicol

I decided to place two tables in a multicol block so that I could save some space and make it look neater.

However, the following happened - the spacing is off on the second block (table is shifted down slightly, text is shifted down quite a bit):
[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}}
            \toprule
            $P$ & $Q$ & $\neg \left(P \land Q \right)$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
            \midrule
            T & T & F & F \\
            T & F & T & T \\
            F & T & T & T \\
            F & F & T & T \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{center}
            \small{Proof of equivalence: $\neg \left(P \land Q \right) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.} 
        \end{center}

    \end{center}
    \columnbreak
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}}
            \toprule
            $P$ & $Q$ & $\neg \left(P \land Q \right)$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
            \midrule
            T & T & F & F \\
            T & F & T & T \\
            F & T & T & T \\
            F & F & T & T \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{center}
           \small{Proof of equivalence: $\neg \left(P \land Q \right) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.} 
        \end{center}
    \end{center}
\end{multicols}
```

Could someone tell me how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal and compilable example.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just pasted my snippet and required imports on Overleaf and it works. However, on my local system, I have more packages and a dedicated .tex and .sty preamble setup, so I think something in there might be interfering.

Comment: You can easily save space by using \centering instead of center.  It should stop at the end of the multicols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to use two mini pages, `tabular*` table and `caption` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \captionsetup{font=small}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccc }
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $\neg (P \land Q )$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
\midrule
T & T & F & F \\
T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & T \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\captionof*{table}{Proof of equivalence: $\neg (P \land Q ) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccc }
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $\neg (P \land Q )$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
\midrule
T & T & F & F \\
T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & T \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\captionof*{table}{Proof of equivalence: $\neg (P \land Q ) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.}
\end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see with extreme pleasure that you love the tables: :-))))))))))))))))) LOL :-)))) +1 for all the users.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much for kind words! Tables are an interesting challenge ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a good idea to shoe-horn the material at hand into a two-column `multicols` environment. Using a `minipage` and (optionally) using `threeparttable` environments to limit the widths of the legends to the widths of the associated `tabular` environments would appear to represent a more straightforward approach.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % for 'threeparttable' environment

\begin{document}
\noindent % <-- important
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} % first 'threeparttable'
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} cccc @{}}
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $\neg (P \land Q )$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
\midrule
T & T & F & F \\
T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & T \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\small\raggedright
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]Proof of equivalence: $\neg (P \land Q ) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}% % <-- the '%' symbol is important
\qquad
\begin{threeparttable} % second 'threeparttable'
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} cccc @{}}
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $\neg (P \land Q )$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
\midrule
T & T & F & F \\
T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & T \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\small\raggedright
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]Proof of equivalence: $\neg (P \land Q ) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With two side-by-side minipage environments, you could achieve the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  Proof of equivalence: $\neg (P \land Q ) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.

  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} cccc @{}}
    \toprule
    $P$ & $Q$ & $\neg (P \land Q )$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
    \midrule
    T & T & F & F \\
    T & F & T & T \\
    F & T & T & T \\
    F & F & T & T \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\centering
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  Proof of equivalence: $\neg (P \land Q ) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$.

  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} cccc @{}}
    \toprule
    $P$ & $Q$ & $\neg (P \land Q )$ & $\neg P \lor \neg Q$\\
    \midrule
    T & T & F & F \\
    T & F & T & T \\
    F & T & T & T \\
    F & F & T & T \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would I be able to put the note on the bottom by moving the \centering tag?

Comment: The \centering command horizontally centers all contents of the corresponding minipage. If you want to show the text below of the tabular, just switch their order in the code.